# Write date modified to filename

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write the date created to the filename of a .csv file. I do the following:

```
created_at = int(os.path.getctime(file1))
filename = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_at).strftime('%H%M')
name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)


 New_dir1 = 'D:\Path'

 dfresource.to_csv(os.path.join(new_dir1, filename))
```

It prints the date created correctly, but how should I write this date to the .csv file correctly? I would like to use the **hours** and **minutes** only. So 12:45 in this example. Filename output: 1245.csv

[image: date modified]

Hope you can help me out with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not using ctime the way you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import datetime

# Targeted filename
filename = 'test.py'

# File creation date UNIX timestamp
created_at = int(os.path.getctime(filename))

# Get hour and minutes
new_name = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_at).strftime('%H%M')

# Get file extension
name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

# New filename 
new_filename = new_name + extension

# Rename file
os.rename(filename, new_filename)

print '[+] File successfully renamed'
```

Comment: Hi @Matt thank's for your great help. However in my code the .csv file is loaded into a data frame (pandas). At the end I am using 

dataframe.to_csv(os.path.join(/path , filename) 


And I use your code to specify the filename: 
created_at = int(os.path.getctime(file1))
        filename = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_at).strftime('%H%M')

It displays the hours and minutes but the fileformat is not specified, whereas normally a csv is the output. What do I wrong?

Comment: Are you appending ".csv" after the %H%M string?